# What is the difference between KV object and Map in google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-beam

What'is the difference between KV object and Map object, and why i must use KV object when i wanna create a PCollection of MAP

```
PCollection<KV<String, String>> createdPCollection = this.p.apply(Create.of(MapObject).withCoder(KvCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of(), StringUtf8Coder.of())));
```

Answer (score 1):

We cannot create of PCollection of Map using Create.of(Map), it directly converted to KV object so to PCollection of KV object, **but we can create a PCollection of using Create.of(List)**

Comment: Great Thanks (y)